# HTTP PUT is creating instead of updating in Angular app

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, http, web-applications, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working in a simple CRUD app with Angular, and when I submit my form updating an element of the table, it creates another element instead of update the same. What is wrong?

**Service Class:**

```js
export class EquipmentsService {
  url = "https://localhost:5001/api/Equipment";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

   Getall(): Observable<Equipments[]>{
    return this.http.get<Equipments[]>(this.url);
  }


  GetWithId(EquipmentsID: number): Observable<Equipments>
  {
    const Url = `${this.url}/${EquipmentsID}`;
    return this.http.get<Equipments>(Url);
  }
  PostEquipment(equipment: Equipments ): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post<Equipments>(this.url, equipment, httpOptions);
  }
  PutEquipment(equipment: Equipments): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.put<Equipments>(this.url, equipment,httpOptions);
  }

  DeleteEquipment(equipmentId: number): Observable<any>
  {
    const Url = `${this.url}/${equipmentId}`;
    return this.http.delete<Number>(Url, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

**Dialog Component:**

```js
export class DialogFormUpdateComponent implements OnInit {

  public titleForm!: string;
  formG!: FormGroup;
  equip!: Equipments;
  id!: number;


  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogFormUpdateComponent>, private fb: FormBuilder,
    private EquipmentService: EquipmentsService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

      console.log(this.id); // It's receiving Id value

      this.EquipmentService.GetWithId(this.id).subscribe(result => {
        this.titleForm = "Update Equipment";
        this.formG = this.fb.group({
          name: [result.name, [Validators.required]],
          serialNumber: [result.serialNumber, [Validators.required]],
          voltage: [result.voltage, [Validators.required]],
          electricCurrent: [result.electricCurrent, [Validators.required]],
          oil: [result.oil, [Validators.required]],
          date: [result.date, [Validators.required]],
        });
      });

  }

  public SendFormUpdate(): void {

    let newDate: moment.Moment = moment.utc(this.formG.value.date).local();
    this.formG.value.date = newDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    const equipment: Equipments = this.formG.value;

    this.EquipmentService.PutEquipment(equipment).subscribe(result => {

      alert("Equipment was updated with success");
      this.formG.reset();
      this.dialogRef.close();
    })
  }

  Cancel() {

    this.dialogRef.close();
    this.formG.reset();

  }
}
```

**Equipment Component:**

```js
export class EquipmentsComponent implements OnInit {
  ELEMENT_DATA!: Equipments[];
  form: any;
  titleForm!: string;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'serialNumber', 'voltage', 'electricCurrent', 'oil', 'date', 'actions'];
  @Output() equipID: EventEmitter<number>= new EventEmitter<number>();


  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Equipments>(this.ELEMENT_DATA);

  constructor(private EquipmentService: EquipmentsService, public dialog: MatDialog,
    public DialogUpate: MatDialog, public DialogComponentUpdate: DialogFormUpdateComponent) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    //getall on start
      this.EquipmentService.Getall().subscribe(result => {
      this.dataSource.data = result as Equipments[];
    });
  }

  //Open Create Form
  NewEquipemnt(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogFormComponent,{
      minWidth: '300px', disableClose: true

    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      //get all
      this.EquipmentService.Getall().subscribe(result => {
        this.dataSource.data = result as Equipments[];
        });
    });
  }

  //Open Update Form
  public UpdateEquipment(EquipId:  number): void
  {

    const dialogRef = this.DialogUpate.open(DialogFormUpdateComponent,{
      minWidth: '300px', disableClose: true,
    });

    dialogRef.componentInstance.id = EquipId;
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
        //get all
        this.EquipmentService.Getall().subscribe(result => {
        this.dataSource.data = result as Equipments[];
        });
    });

  }


}
```

My update button get a data of element will be updated, but when I click in submit is created other element in my DB

**Equipment Controller:**

```cs
namespace TreeApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("Api/[Controller]")]
    public class EquipmentController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ContextEquipment _ContextEquipment;

        public EquipmentController (ContextEquipment context)
        {
            _ContextEquipment = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Equipments>>> GetAllAsync()
        {
         return await _ContextEquipment.Equipment.ToListAsync();
        }

        [HttpGet("{EquipmentsID}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Equipments>> GetEquipmentAsync(int EquipmentsID)
        {
            Equipments equipment = await _ContextEquipment.Equipment.FindAsync(EquipmentsID);

            if(equipment == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return equipment;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Equipments>> PostEquipmentAsync(Equipments equipments)
        {   
            await _ContextEquipment.Equipment.AddAsync(equipments);
            await _ContextEquipment.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok();
        }
        [HttpPut]
        public async Task<ActionResult> PutEquipmentAsync(Equipments equipments)
        {
            _ContextEquipment.Equipment.Update(equipments);
            await _ContextEquipment.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok();

        }

        [HttpDelete("{EquipmentsID}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteEquipmentAsync(int EquipmentsID)
        {
           Equipments equipment = await _ContextEquipment.Equipment.FindAsync(EquipmentsID);
            _ContextEquipment.Remove(equipment);
            await _ContextEquipment.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup:**

```cs
namespace TreeApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
    
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddDbContext<ContextEquipment>(options => options.UseSqlServer
                (Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionDB")));
            services.AddCors();
        }
    
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
    
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
    
            app.UseAuthorization();
    
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is in your API. Can you add the code for the Equipment endpoint? It's clearly selecting the wrong route/method somehow.

Comment: @JimJimson yes, of course. I did add now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Concern

In your `SendFormUpdate` method, you missed out to assign `id` which is your primary key for the `equipment`.

> DialogFormUpdateComponent

```js
public SendFormUpdate(): void {

    let newDate: moment.Moment = moment.utc(this.formG.value.date).local();
    this.formG.value.date = newDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    const equipment: Equipments = this.formG.value;

    this.EquipmentService.PutEquipment(equipment).subscribe(result => {

      alert("Equipment was updated with success");
      this.formG.reset();
      this.dialogRef.close();
    })
}
```

According to [`DbContext.Update(Object)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext_Update_System_Object_),

> For entity types with generated keys if an entity has its primary key
> value set then it will be tracked in the Modified state.
>
> **If the
> primary key value is not set then it will be tracked in the Added
> state. This helps ensure new entities will be inserted, while existing
> entities will be updated.**
>
> An entity is considered to have its primary
> key value set if the primary key property is set to anything other
> than the CLR default for the property type.

**Thus, new `Equipment` record will be created instead of update the existing record.**

---

### Solution

Make sure that you need to assign `id` (primary key) with value to `equipment` to solve the concern above.

> DialogFormUpdateComponent

```js
public SendFormUpdate(): void {
    ...
    
    const equipment: Equipments = this.formG.value;
    equipment.id = this.id;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Woow, It's work!! Thank you for answer and explanation :)